# Mvvmcross MvxListview MvxItemTemplate resource not found

Tags: android, binding, mvvmcross

I am building a Android app in Xamarin with Mvvmcross. In this app i need a F.a.q. page, for which I need a listview. Using the MvxListView i succeeded to display the items without a template. The weird thing is when i bind the MvxItemTemplate it doesn't compile giving me the error.

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'MvxItemTemplate' with value '@layout/FaqCategoryLayout'. (APT0000)

The binding looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/Page"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <Mvx.MvxListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/FaqCategoryLayout"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Collection" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the layout

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Text Category"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I saw a lot more posts on this subject where most of them where easily fixed. But none of them worked for me. I am very sure that the layout names are exactly the same. Also when i use the same layout on a button background it does compile like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind on this. I was an idiot. I rewatched the video from mvvmcross n+1 on the listview and noticed one essential keyword: "Lowercase".

So setting the ItemTemplate in lowercase did do the trick

```
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/faqcategorylayout"
```